# Evaluate: $\int_0^{2a} y \sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{4} y} dy$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate

$$\int_0^{2a} y \sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{4} y} \ dy$$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try integration by parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, you could make life a bit simpler.
Let
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{y}{4}}=t \implies y=2 \left(1-2 t^2\right)\implies dy=-8t\,dt$$
So,
$$\int y \sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{y}{4}}\right)\,dy=16\int  t \left(2 t^2-1\right) \sin ^{-1}(t)\,dt$$

Now, as @MathIsFun commented, *"try integration by parts"*.